# Meaning of word 'be friends'

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns, british-english

On the internet I read the word *friends* have many meaning.

> **I am friends** with my last schoolmate from university.
>
> I have got five **friends** from Indonesia.
>
> Those people are **friends of** Lord Voldemort.

The first form is a verb, the second is plural noun and the third is plural noun too.

Am I right?

What is different between nouns **members of** and **friends of**? Do we use the first word only with things and the second word with people?

Can I say:

> I am a **member of** British parliament.
>
> I am  **friends of** British parliament.

Comment: I don't the first ''friend'' in your example is a verb, but "befriend" can be a verb.

Comment: @M.A.R. I mean the form _be friends with_ .

Comment: Yes, I mean that one too. The verb there is "be", not "friends".

Comment: @M.A.R. Then how we call form _be friends with_ in British English?

Comment: I'd just call it a fixed expression. Let's see what the answerers have to say.

Comment: @M.A.R. Is this sentence correct? _I am friends of British parliament._

Comment: No, IMO the preposition choice is incorrect, and it should either be *I am friends with* or *I am a friend of* but this is no expert opinion.

Comment: Member applies to a group or organization.  If you are a member, you are an internal part of that group.  A friend is external to the group, tied to it through some form of relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Friends is a plural noun.
In your first sentence the verb is 'am'.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/friend

You can be a friend of someone or be friends with someone.

You can be a friend of a society or group which you support (usually financially).

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/member

You can be a member of a club or group to which you belong.

So there are Members of Parliament but there aren't any Friends of the British Parliament because it doesn't accept donations, apparently.